# Catch the event when a youtube flash video is done playing using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I'm supposed to create a sort of youtube video rotator using jquery. I've looked around and there seemed to be no plugin that's fit for the requirement. Not even a solution.

Maybe I'll just try to make this. So now, how can I determine that a youtube video is done playing and automatically play the next, using Jquery, or simply just javascript?

And if you happen to know a plugin which may help, please point out.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't YouTube have a playlist functionality where you can queue up videos to auto-rotate? -- **EDIT** Case in point: http://www.youtube.com/custom_player/

Answer (score 12):

First you have to make sure the youtube player you're embedding supports javascript by passing `enablejsapi=1` as a get param. Here's how I insert a (chromeless) player using SWFObject:

```
    var player_id = "your_player_id";
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var url = "http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=" + player_id;
    swfobject.embedSWF(url, player_id, '320', '240', "9.0.0", null, null, params, {'id': player_id});
```

Then you need to add a global function that is called when the player is ready, and in that add a listener for when a video is complete:

```
    var player = null;

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(player_id) {
      player = document.getElementById(player_id);
      player.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'playerStateChanged');
      player.loadVideoById(youtube_video_id);
    };

    function playerStateChanged(state) {
      // State code 0 means playback ended
      if (state == 0) {
        player.loadVideoById(next_video_id);
      }
    };
```

I wrote this code for my youtube playlist bookmarklet. Here's a link if you want a working example: http://zaius.github.com/youtube_playlist/

And if you want to do anything more in depth, here's the youtube javascript reference where I worked out how to do all this: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html